# Is there a better way to get info from 2 tables

Tags: php, database, join

In database the users have a row called weapon_id which determines what weapon he uses from another table with weapons.

Is there a better way to get that info like join table or something?

```
$user_get = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['sess_id']."'");
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_get);

$weapon_get = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM weapons WHERE weapon_id = '".$user['weapon_id']."'");
$weapon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($weapon_get);
```

Comment: Yes, you would use a join and you could do it in one query.  Could you paste the result that you would like to have?

Comment: When i echo it out on a profile for example i show what weapon they are using echo $weapon['damage'] $weapon['name'] and the rest of the user stats such as $user['name'] $user['hp'] etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a join like this

```
  $user_get = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM members m LEFT JOIN weapons w ON(w.weapon_id=m.weapon_id)  WHERE m.id = '".$_SESSION['sess_id']."'");
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_get);
```

**change the join type as per your requirement. the above query for only example**

- INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH
  tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows
  from the right table
- RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched
  rows from the left table
- FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

**more about join [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)** 
**AND also check this http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `weapon` as w
JOIN `user` as u
on w.weapon_id  = u.weapon_id
and u.id  = :session_id
```

How about this ?